# How to define static member variable from class template with specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, partial-specialization, class-template

OK I have this code:

```
// default implementation just uses a mutex to serialize access
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct kernport {
    static const bool atomic = false;

    // constructor
    kernport(T value=T()) {
        set(value);
    }

    // get/set value
    T    get()         const { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_); return value_;  }
    void set(const T& value) { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_); value_ = value; }

private:
    mutable std::mutex lock_;
    T value_;
};


// specialization if std::atomic<T> exists
template <typename T>
struct kernport<T, void_type<decltype(std::atomic<T>())>> {
    static const bool atomic = true;

    // constructor
    kernport(T value=T()) {
        set(value);
    }

    // query port value
       T get() const         { return value_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);  }
    void set(const T& value) { value_.store(value, std::memory_order_release); }

private:
    std::atomic<T> value_;
};
```

If I try to check `kernport<bool>::atomic`, I get the dreaded undefined reference.  OK, so I need to define the member outside of the class:

```
template <typename T> const bool kernport<T>::atomic;
```

Unfortunately, doing that, I get:

> inc/skunk/dataflow/kernel.h:472:47: error: template definition of
>   non-template ‘const bool sk::kernport::atomic’  template  const bool kernport::atomic;

And for the life of me I can find the right syntax.  How do I write this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const bool kernport<T1, T2>::atomic;

template <typename T1>
const bool kernport<T1, void>::atomic;
```

?

Don't forget the second (defaulted to `void`) template parameter.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either way, I get the undefined reference again when it does compile.

Comment: @gct - Sorry: error of mine: I've seen `atomic` in the specialization but not in the main version. I'm too tired today.

Comment: Two template parameters doesn't work either, I get an undefined reference error.

Comment: @gct - with both? One for the main, one for the specialization?

Comment: I get "template definition of non-template <variable definition>" with the second statement.

Comment: @gct - the bad part is that I compile it (and link) in a toy example... frankly I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: I'm finding my specialization doesn't work either, because std::atomic uses a static_assert which breaks SFINAE...